# jquery POST being sent as GET

Tags: jquery, ajax

The code is working, however it is being sent as GET in the URL.

I have looked at other questions here but none seem relevant.

```
$("#securityInfoUpdate").click(function() {

        var newUserName = $('#securityInfoUserName').find(":input").val();
        var newPassword = $('#securityInfoPassword').find(":input").val();
    $.post( "ajaxProcessing.php", { username: newUserName, password:newPassword } )
                .done(function( data ) {
                var success = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                if (success == 1){          
                    $("#securityInfoMessage").html('YES!! DATABASE CHANGED');

                }else if(success == 2){
                    $("#securityInfoMessage").html('PROBLEM BUDDY!');
                }

            });
});
```

It is also causing a page refresh. What could be the reason for this?

Let me know if other information is required or relevant.

HTML

```
<form id= "securityInfoValuePairs">
                        Change username and password:<br/>
                        <div id="securityInfoMessage">
                        </div>
                        <div id="securityInfoUserName">
                        </div>
                        <div id="securityInfoPassword">
                            <label for="passwordLate">NEW or OLD Password:</label>
                            <input type="text" name="passwordLate" placeholder="PLEASE ENTER A PASSWORD">
                        </div>
                        <button id="securityInfoUpdate">UPDATE</button>
                    </form>
```

BTW info and input fields in form are supplied by js via loalStorage

Comment: Is your code executed when the page loads or from an event like a button click?

Comment: If it's causing a page refresh, probably means you aren't preventing the default event for whatever you use to trigger this code?

Comment: Can you add the HTML that goes with `#securityInfoUpdate`?

Comment: Is that button inside a `<form>`?

Comment: Is the button in a form and are there other buttons marked as "submit"? If this is the only button in a form then it can behave as a submit button in which case you'll need to prevent default submission.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default type for a [button](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button) is submit and the default method for a [form](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.3) is GET, so when you click your button, since it has no specified type and the form no specified method, and you're not using any JavaScript to prevent the default behavior, it's submitting the form and reloading the page.

An easy fix would be to use `return false` or `.preventDefault()` to prevent the button from submitting the form while making your AJAX request. You can see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/event-preventdefault-vs-return-false) for a discussion on the differences between the methods.

Comment: Thanks will accept in 2 minutes. Given for fuller not faster answer!

Answer (score 2):

Add `return false;` to the end of the `click` function:

```
$("#securityInfoUpdate").click(function() { 
    ....

    return false;
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Accepted the fuller answer though. Thx again!